# Deserialize Json that includes key and value keywords

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a Json that looks like this:

```
{
 "Title:": "StructureTitle",
 "Description:" : "StructureDescription",
 "Contents": "[{"Key":"FirstKey","Value":"FirstValue"},{"Key":"SecondKey","Value":"SecondValue"},{"Key":"ThirdKey","Value":"ThirdValue"}]"
}
```

And I cannot figure out how to deserialize it because the Contents section is specifying what is the key and what is the value.

I've defined my classes this way

```
    public class Info
    {
       public string Title{ get; set; }
       public string Description{ get; set; }
       public Contents Contents{ get; set; }
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Contents {

        [DataMember(Name = "FirstKey")]
        public string FirstKey{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SecondKey")]
        public string SecondKey{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ThirdKey"]
        public string ThirdKey { get; set; }

     }
```

And I'm trying to perform the deserialization this way:

```
var text = "{ "Title:": "StructureTitle", "Description:" : "StructureDescription", "Contents": "[{"Key":"FirstKey","Value":"FirstValue"},{"Key":"SecondKey","Value":"SecondValue"},{"Key":"ThirdKey","Value":"ThirdValue"}]" }"
JToken token = JObject.Parse(text);
var x = token.SelectToken("Contents");
Contents c = x.ToObject<Contents>();
```

This is the error I'm getting:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value

Comment: Don't put quotes around the array: `"[ ]"`.

Comment: is Contents actually coming as a string?

Comment: The line of code `var text = "{ "Title:": "StructureTitle", ...` doesn't even compile, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/0FNeRx.  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Contents is actually an array of key/value pairs.  Some serializers will put that right in a Dictionary<string,string>, but I think JSON.net is different by default. You could write your own KVP object like class KVP {string key; string value;}and then making Info.Contents a List<KVP> Otherwise you’ll have to write your own deserializer for your structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "{ \"Title: \": \"StructureTitle\", \"Description: \" : \"StructureDescription\", \"Contents\": [{ \"Key\":\"FirstKey\",\"Value\":\"FirstValue\"},{ \"Key\":\"SecondKey\",\"Value\":\"SecondValue\"},{ \"Key\":\"ThirdKey\",\"Value\":\"ThirdValue\"}] }";
JToken token = JObject.Parse(text);
var x = token.SelectToken("Contents");
Contents c = x.ToObject<Contents>();
```